# How to connect adwords conversion tracking and analytics goals?

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-ads, google-tag-manager

I am using AdWords conversion tracking using AdWords and Tag Manger. What I did is the following:

> 1) **In AdWords**: **Tools** -> **Conversion** -> **New conversion** -> **Website** -> Fill in all
>   the conversion details [Lead conversion](Name,Category,Value,count
>   ....). After that I copied Conversion Id, Conversion Label
>
> 2) In **Tag Manger**: **Tags** -> **New** -> **Conversion linker**
>   (default page) -> **Trigger for all pages**
>
> 3) In **Tag Manger**: **Tags**-**>New**-> **Google add conversion
>   tracking** (Paste the conversion id , label) -> **Triggered for all
>   pages**

So now my conversion tracking is in the Unverified state. I expect it to verify within a few hours.

**However, I doubt that it is going to work.**

I have a contact form on my website. ***My goal: People should fill in the contact page and reach the thank you page***. I already setup the destination goal with a funnel. In Google Analytics, everything is working properly and I am getting the correct details.

But in Google AdWords conversion, how will it work? ***Because I didn't inform AdWords that contact form submission is my goal***. Also this conversion tracking is being triggered on every page, not only the contact page.

Please help to clarify my doubt. What is going to happen if I have more goals in AdWords? Did I miss anything in the conversion tracking?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Differences between Ads and Analytics

Google Analytics and Google Ads are two different tools and the data registered may differ. The main difference is that Ads track users with clicks and Analytics with sessions. Please check [this post](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034383?hl=en) to clarify the concept.

Having that in mind, you can't have the same conversions on both platforms:

> In Analytics, Conversion Rate is the percentage of users that convert
>   on at least one of the Goals you have defined for that view. This is
>   different than the AdWords Conversion Rate you see in your Google Ads
>   account. In Google Ads, the Conversion Rate refers to the percent of
>   clicks that end in a Google Ads conversion, defined by the AdWords
>   Conversion Tracking code.

What you can do is import Ads conversions into Analytics reports (what you have done) [or import  Analytics goals and transactions into Ads](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/2375435).

### Ads conversion code

It depends on which version of Analytics you are using. In the case of [gtag.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/?hl=en) (connects Google Analytics, Google Ads, and Google Marketing Platform) you just need to use the same code in all the URLs of your site.

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-123456789"></script>
  <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());
      gtag('config', 'AW-123456789');
  </script>
```

and, in the thank you page, just execute the conversion snippet:

```
<script>
      gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-123456789/AbC-D_efG-h12_34-567',
        'value': 1.0,
        'currency': 'USD'
      });
    </script>
```

That's the way to send Google Ads a conversion. Analytics goals must be defined [through the admin dashboard](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012040?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

I think your Conversion tracking on Google Ads is wrong. You want to track the form submit (button click/thank you page) while you've set up the trigger for all pages.

To fix this, you should change the condition for firing the trigger. Example below:
[image]

You can also config the trigger for firing when people click the submit button, or when people landing on the /thankyou page.

I hope this helps!